# Prove of measurability of region under unsigned measurable function without Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the measurability of the graph of an unsigned function without using Fubini's theorem. It will be the best if someone can give some comment on whether my claims are correct.

$f$ is measurable, there exists an increasing sequence of unsigned simple functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $\{f_n\}\to f$ pointwise. Explicitly, if $f_n=\sum_{m=1}^{M_n}c_{n,m}\textbf{1}_{E_{n,m}}$ for measurable subsets $E_{n,m}$, then
$$S_n:=\{(x,t):0\leq t\leq f_n(x)\}=\bigcup_{m=1}^{M_n}E_{n,m}\times[0,c_{n,m}]$$
is a measurable set since product of measurable subsets is measurable. Meanwhile, as $f_n\to f$ pointwise from below, we have
$$\{(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^d\times[0,+\infty]:0\leq t\leq f(x)\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n:=S.$$
Countable union preserves measurability, so $S$ is measurable.

Comment: What is an unsigned function?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy meaning a function that send $\mathbb{R}^d$ to non-negative real numbers

Answer (score 1):

The equality
$$
\{(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^d\times[0,+\infty]:0\leq t\leq f(x)\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n
$$
is not correct in my opinion.
Consider the constant functions $f=1$ and $f_n=1-1/n$.
Then your construction would yield
$$
\{(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^d\times[0,+\infty]:0\leq t\leq f(x)\}\neq
\{(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^d\times[0,+\infty]:0\leq t< f(x)\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I suppose $\{(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^d×[0,+\infty]:0≤t<f(x)\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n$ is correct. Then together with 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676445/prove-that-the-graph-of-a-measurable-function-is-measurable-and-has-lebesgue-me
we can arrive at the measurability of the desired set.